# Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I got stuck on this question when I tried solving it using the numpy package. My idea was that I would multiply and keep a list of all the calculations I did of the 3 digit numbers ranging from 100 to 999, then check through the list to see which ones are a palindrome and save them. Finally, I would order the list and get the largest palindrome. Code below shows what I tried to do.

```
import numpy as np

def void():
    list1 = np.array(range(100,999))
    list2 = np.array(range(100,999))
    k = []
    
    for i,j in zip(list1,list2):
        k.append(np.multiply(list1,list2))
        
    b = []
    
    for x in range(0,len(k)):
        if(reverseNum(k[x])==k[x]):
            b.append(k[x])
            
    print(b)
    print(b[-1])
    
def reverseNum(num):
    rev = 0
    
    while(num>0):
        rem = num % 10
        rev = (rev*10) +rem
        num = num // 10
        
    return rev  
    
void()
```

However, when I try to check if the numbers in the list are a palindrome, I get the following bug:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                    
  File "main.py", line 40, in <module>                                                                                
    void()                                                                                                            
  File "main.py", line 22, in void                                                                                    
    if(reverseNum(k[x]),k[x]):                                                                                        
  File "main.py", line 31, in reverseNum                                                                              
    while(num>0):                                                                                                     
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Does this mean that it is not possible to use numpy as a method to solve this problem? If it is, where am I going wrong?

EDIT:
What I have tried so far (since it was asked):
Based on the error messages, I tried using `np.equal` as well as `np.greater` instead of checking `if(reverseNum(k[x])==k[x])` and `num>0` but it gives the same error.

Comment: You haven't told us what happened when you tried fixing it as suggested.

Comment: Sorry tried fixing how @superbrain?

Comment: @superbrain I do but I was not able to solve it. Explained what I have tried in edit.

Comment: You are treating the arrays as lists. Aside from the container, there's nothing numpy in what you're doing.

Comment: I see what you are saying @MadPhysicist

Comment: I tried typecasting the array of the product as a list. It still gives the same error. Any thoughts on why that wouldn't work @MadPhysicist?

Comment: Run a debugger, or print out `num` on the line that is raising an error. That is normally how we handle these things.

Comment: @SashaHurwitz I still don't see you trying the suggestions from the error message...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue stems from the your line including the `zip`. My code below isn't pretty, but attempts to follow your approach loosely.

```py
import numpy as np

def void():
    list1 = np.array(range(100,1000))  # you want to include '999'
    list2 = np.array(range(100,1000))
    k = []
    
    for i,j in zip(list1,list2):
        k.append(np.multiply(list1,j))
        
    b = []
    
    for r, row in enumerate(k):
        for c, cell in enumerate(row):
            if reverseNum(cell)==cell:
                b.append(cell)
            
    print(b)
    print(max(b))

    
def reverseNum(num):
    rev = 0
    
    while(num>0):
        rem = num % 10
        rev = (rev*10) +rem
        num = num // 10
        
    return rev
    
void()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was trying to figure out. I didn't know about the enumerate function and I realize now that I didn't understand zip completely. This was so helpful. It kept bugging me why I couldn't figure out any of the suggested methods to fix it.

Comment: Honestly, the zip is unnecessary, since it's been immediately unzipped with the ```for i,j```. You'd be better off with just iterating over one of the lists... ```for j in list2:```...

Answer (score 1):

A NumPy way assuming the result has six digits (it can't have more, as 999<sup>2</sup> is 998001):

```
import numpy as np

v = np.arange(100, 1000)                     # the range of three-digit numbers
a = np.outer(v, v)                           # all the products
print(a[(a // 100000 == a % 10) &            # first digit == sixth digit
        (a // 10000 % 10 == a // 10 % 10) &
        (a // 1000 % 10 == a // 100 % 10)].max())
```

Prints `906609`.

Double checking with pure Python:

```
>>> max(x*y
        for x in range(100, 1000)
        for y in range(100, 1000)
        if str(x*y) == str(x*y)[::-1])
906609
```

Answer (score 0):

Why does it have to use numpy?

```py
# test if palindrome based on str
def is_palindrome(number: int):
    converted_to_string = str(number)
    return converted_to_string == converted_to_string[::-1]


# product of two three-digit numbers
you_right = []
values = []
for x in range(999, 99, -1):
    for y in range(999, 99, -1):
        product = x*y
        if is_palindrome(product):
            values.append((x, y))
            you_right.append(product)
winner = you_right.index(max(you_right))
print(values[winner])
```

```py
# output
(993, 913)
```

Comment: It's only because I wanted to know if it is possible to do it that way. I know how to do it the traditional way.

Answer (score 0):

Another real NumPy solution, using your way to reverse the numbers (fixing it mostly by using `.any()` as suggested in the error message, which you stubbornly refused to try).

```
v = np.arange(100, 1000)
a = np.outer(v, v)

num = a.copy()
rev = num * 0
while (m := num > 0).any():
    rev[m] = rev[m] * 10 + num[m] % 10
    num[m] //= 10

print(a[rev == a].max())
```

Without the mask `m` you get the same result (906609), but it's safer with it. Otherwise products with five digits aren't reversed correctly, like 101*102=10302 becomes 203010 instead of 20301.